# iDevices full screen scroll wheel

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown, that I want to redirect the user depending on which option they select:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotopage(selval){
var value = selval.options[selval.selectedIndex].value;
window.location.href=value;
</script>

<select style="float:right" onchange="gotopage(this)">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="http://www.lap.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
<option value="http://www.msn.com">MSN</option>
</select>
```

But, when I go change it, the page stays the same.
Any idea why?

Comment: Did the posted answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript function has no closing `}` bracket

Here is it working as you expected with the bracket added: http://jsfiddle.net/3Hfhr/